# Iphone : while play one song another song overlap.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, avaudioplayer

In my app song play from ipod library through AVAudioPlayer,

problem is that when one song is play & select second song,
second song overlap,

i try to stop the song with call this method

```
- (IBAction)player_stop {
  theAudio.delegate = nil;
  [theAudio release];
  theAudio = nil;    
}
```

I try this method but not going in this condition

```
if (theAudio.isPlaying == YES){        
  [theAudio release];
  theAudio = nil;
}
```

theAudio is Object of AVAudioplayer,

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
if (theAudio.isPlaying == YES){        
   [theAudio stop];
}
```